# Swift - XLActionController - Change cell color

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am using the library https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController in order to create a custom action sheet. Everything works but I cannot find the way to change the color of the cell.

I have managed to change the background `CollectionView` color but I cannot figure out how to change the color of just the cell.

```
let actionController = SkypeActionController()
actionController.settings.statusBar.showStatusBar = false
actionController.collectionView.backgroundColor = mySavedColor    
actionController.addAction(Action(AlertString, style: .Default, handler: { action in

}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the `SkypeCell`, you have to change its `initialize` function. Look for `backgroundColor = .clearColor()` and then put the color you're using.

In a general case, you can change the cell's backgroundColor when `onConfigureCellForAction` is called. You can set a block to this of your `ActionController`:

```
public override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String? = nil, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle? = nil) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

    // Do other setup    

   onConfigureCellForAction = { cell, action, indexPath in
       cell.backgroundColor = .redColor()
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you should be able to do the same in the xib file of your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Using the last version (3.0.0) of the library XLActionController and Swift 3, you have the option to change the background color using this code:

```
let actionController = SkypeActionController()
actionController.backgroundColor = .red
```

It is a new feature in this version of the library.